# Cannot see the Image type in System.Drawing namespace in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, image, dimensions

I'm trying to write a program that sorts images in specific folder by ther dimensions and moves little images to another folder via simple .NET console application. I decided to use System.Drawing.Image class to get the image dimentions from an image file. But I face following error:

> The type or namespace name 'Image' could not be found (are you missing
>   a using directive or an assembly referrence?)

What exactly did I do wrong and why it doesn't see this class?
Here are the complete code of my program:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using System.Drawing;

namespace ImageSort
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string targetPath = @"d:\SmallImages";
            string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(@"d:\Images");
            foreach (string path in files)
            {
                if (File.Exists(path))
                {
                    Image newImage = Image.FromFile(path);
                    var Width = (int)(newImage.Width);
                    var Height = (int)(newImage.Height);
                    if (Width * Height < 660000) {
                        System.IO.File.Move(path, targetPath);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to add a reference  : `System.Drawing.dll.`

In `Solution Explorer`, right-click on the `References` node and choose Add `Reference` and find `System.Drawing.dll`.

Comment: Yes, it helped! I was such a rookie in this. Thanks!

Comment: This is such a huge help for a rookie.

Comment: Why? Why do we have to do this for System.Drawing but nothing else that I've seen so far?

Comment: @Clonkex, you might find some answers on this Microsoft [System.Drawing.Common only supported on Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/core/compatibility/core-libraries/6.0/system-drawing-common-windows-only) article.

Comment: Which one to use? 2.0 of 2.4?

Answer (score 17):

The answer to this issue for .NET Core 3.1 is to simply install [System.Drawing.Common](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Drawing.Common/) from NuGet.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to @feganmeister answer, you can install the NuGet package using `dotnet` CLI command from a terminal:

Navigate to the project directory and run the following command:

```
cd <project-directory>
dotnet add package System.Drawing.Common
```